# Arrays and scanf issues; values to use with scanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

This is a simple program to compute ages of people in the room.
I am at the very initial stage, and now I see that I do not know which variables (I mean variables that I declare before scanf and then placeholders within scanf) to use for scanf; how to choose and apply a correct variable. Is there a resource that could explain in plain English these issues?
Here is the program:

```
// Ages people by a year. Arrays

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    // determine number of people
    int n;
    do
    {
        printf("Number of people in room: ");
        scanf ("%i", &n);
    }
    while (n<1); // get the number of people in the room, pass through user
                 // again and again until the user gives a positive integer

    // declare array in which to store everyone's age

    int ages[n];
    int  i;


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Age of person #%i: ", i + 1); // person number 1, person number 2, etc
        scanf ("%d", ages[i]); // store the age in the i-th part of the array ages
    }

    // report everyone's age a year hence
    printf("Time passes...\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf(" A year from now person #%i will be %i years old.\n", i + 1, ages[i] + 1); 
        // we add 1 year to previous age

    }
 }
```

Comment: Replace `scanf ("%d", ages[i]);` with `scanf ("%d", &ages[i]);`

Comment: @psyco thank you very much! it did work. if you have a minute, could you please explain why? I have read that scanf doesn't require & if used for arrays. What is the difference in the logic between adding `&ages[i]` and `ages[i]` or even `ages` (only your version works)?

Comment: See, when we use `scanf()` , we need to pass the reference of the variable where we want to store the value. what you passed, was the value instead. Just add `&`  before it or use `scanf("%d",ages+i);` both are same.

Answer (score 2):

[`scanf("%d")`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) expects an address as an argument. Therefore, replace

```
scanf ("%d", ages[i]);
```

with

```
scanf ("%d", ages + i);
```

(or `&ages[i]` but that's personal preference.)

Comment: thank you! I've just learned a new way of doing it - haven't yet seen `something+1` used instead of & :)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects pointer to some variable in order to change it's value - otherwise it will get some copy that won't affect the real variable.

this line :
`scanf ("%d", ages[i]);`
dereference `ages` and returns an integer, not a pointer to an integer.
change it to be 
`scanf ("%d", &ages[i]);`
the `&` will extract the memory address of `ages[i]` and pass it as a pointer to `scanf`